# Uncaught TypeError: this.setMinHeight is not a function using TUI editor, ejs, node.js

Tags: javascript, html, toast-ui-editor

I'm trying to use [TUI editor](https://nhn.github.io/tui.editor/latest/) in `ejs template` and `nodejs`.

I can't solve this problem and couldn't find any data about this.
[image]

I just followed the guide.

1. add `css CDN` on head.
2. create `<div id="editor"></div>`
3. add `<script> CDN` under `<div>`
4. make `instance`

What is the problem? Same problem happens using `html` not `ejs`.
I'm going crazy.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">

  <!-- Bootstrap -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- TUI editor -->
  <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor.css" /> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor.min.css" />

  <!-- axios -->
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="box write-box shadow">
    <div id="editor"></div>
    <!-- TUI editor -->
    <script src="https://uicdn.toast.com/editor/latest/toastui-editor-all.min.js"></script>
  </div>

  <!-- scripts -->
  <script>
    const editor = toastui.Editor({
      el: document.querySelector('#editor'),
    });
    

    editor.getMarkdown();
  </script>
  
  
  <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you forgot the `new` keyword:

```
const editor = new toastui.Editor({
  el: document.querySelector('#editor'),
});
```

Comment: Oops... It was so simple mistake.
I wrote it down at first, but it seems to have disappeared while fixing it.